# CURL command to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, telegram

I got this CURL query:

```
curl -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto" -F chat_id=<chatid> -F photo="@photo.jpg"
```

to send a photo to my telegram bot.

Now I'd like to translate this query into js code (using a Ajax request) and this is what I got so far:

```js
let token = "yourBotToken",
  chatId = "yourUserChatId";

$("#fileInput").on('change', function() {
  let data = this.files[0];
  console.log(data)
  $.ajax({
    url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${chatId}`,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS");
      console.log(arguments)
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("ERROR");
      console.log(arguments)
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Note that I get back the error message ...

```
description: "Bad Request: there is no photo in the request"
```

... every single time from the telegram api. How can I fix this issue and where is it located?

**Any help would be really appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe axios package help to you?
https://github.com/delirius325/axios-curlirize

Answer (score 0):

Because you not send photo with request 
Use

```
$("#fileInput").on('change', function() { 
    let data = new FormData() ;
    data.append('photo', this.files[0]) ;
    $.ajax({ url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendPhoto? chat_id=${chatId}`, 
        type: "POST", 
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        data: data, 
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.log(data)
        }, 
        error: function(err) { 
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(err);
        } 
    });
});
```